# How do I use DbContext to correctly persist an unattached object graph?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

It's entirely possible that I'm using DbContext particularly badly, but I've ended up with a situation where I'm trying to save an unattached object graph where not all of the elements of the graph are new. e.g. I have a POCO entity like this :

```
var item = new MyClass();
item.RelationshipOne = myExistingItem; //loaded by some other mechanism
item.RelationshipTwo = new MyOtherClass();
```

Currently my insert or update method contains code  a little like this :

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
  context.Entry(item).State = item.ID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But this fails because it sets the state of `myExistingItem` to whatever the root `item` state is (so when I call SaveChanges it tries to recreate an already existing item in the database and throws a primary key violation error).

Is there anything I can do to automagically detect changes and pre-existing objects, or do I have to write code to examine the object graph myself?

Comment: Does the using statement not answer that question for you?